# Attempting to reference a deleted function inside xmemory0 on threaded sockets class

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, class

I'm trying to finish this threaded sockets class. This is what I've got so far:

```
#pragma once
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
//---------------------------------------------------CLASS
class AsyncSockets
{
public:
    int StartSockets(int, void(*)(SOCKET, sockaddr*, int, std::atomic<bool>&));
    static const int FAIL_SUCCESS, FAIL_INIT_WS, FAIL_BIND_SOCKET, FAIL_ASYNCSELECT, FAIL_LISTEN, FAIL_ACCEPT;
    bool StopSockets();
private:
    /*static*/ void(*Functiane)(SOCKET, sockaddr*, int, std::atomic<bool>&);
    struct RunThread {
        std::thread Thread;
        std::atomic<bool> Running = true;
    };
    void AcceptLoop();
    SOCKET Socket; std::atomic<bool> running = false;
    std::vector<AsyncSockets::RunThread>ThreadList;
    void StartFunc(SOCKET, sockaddr*, int, int);
    std::thread loopaccepter;
    std::thread deleteInvalid;
};
//-------------------------------------STARTFUNC---PRIVATE
void AsyncSockets::StartFunc(SOCKET socketa, sockaddr* sockaddra, int sockaddrinfolena, int BoolIndex) {
    if (socketa != INVALID_SOCKET) {
        (*Functiane)(socketa, sockaddra, sockaddrinfolena, ThreadList[BoolIndex].Running);
    }else{
        closesocket(socketa); ThreadList[BoolIndex].Running = false; return;
    }
    closesocket(socketa);
    ThreadList[BoolIndex].Running = false;
    return;
}
//------------------------------------ACCEPTLOOP---PRIVATE
void AsyncSockets::AcceptLoop() {
    while (true) {
        struct sockaddr *AddressInfo = NULL; int addrinfoLen;
        if (running) {
            int temp = ThreadList.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++){
                if (i != temp - 1) {
                    if (!ThreadList[i].Running){
                        if (ThreadList[i].Thread.joinable()) ThreadList[i].Thread.join();
                        ThreadList[i].Running = true; ThreadList[i].Thread = std::thread(&AsyncSockets::StartFunc, this, accept(Socket, AddressInfo, &addrinfoLen), AddressInfo, addrinfoLen, i); }
                }else{
                    if (!ThreadList[i].Running) { 
                        if (ThreadList[i].Thread.joinable()) ThreadList[i].Thread.join();
                        ThreadList[i].Running = true; ThreadList[i].Thread = std::thread(&AsyncSockets::StartFunc, this, accept(Socket, AddressInfo, &addrinfoLen), AddressInfo, addrinfoLen, i);}
                    else { ThreadList.push_back({ std::thread(&AsyncSockets::StartFunc, this, accept(Socket, AddressInfo, &addrinfoLen), AddressInfo, addrinfoLen, i + 1), true });}
                }
            }

        }else return;
    }
}
//-----------------------------------STARTSOCKETS---PUBLIC
int AsyncSockets::StartSockets(int port, void(*functian)(SOCKET, sockaddr*, int, std::atomic<bool>&)) {

    //DeclaringShiet
    int recvbuflen = 512;

    //InitWinsock
    WSADATA WsaDat;
    int nResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WsaDat);
    if (nResult != 0)
    {
        return FAIL_INIT_WS;
    }

    //BuildAddr
    SOCKADDR_IN SockAddr;
    SockAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    //BindSocket
    if (bind(Socket, (LPSOCKADDR)&SockAddr, sizeof(SockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return FAIL_BIND_SOCKET;
    }
    //StartListening
    if (listen(Socket, 10) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        return FAIL_LISTEN;
    }
    //StartAccepting
    running = true;
    Functiane = (*functian);
    loopaccepter = std::thread(&AsyncSockets::AcceptLoop, this);
}
//------------------------------------STOPSOCKETS---PUBLIC
bool AsyncSockets::StopSockets() {
    running = false;
    loopaccepter.join();
    closesocket(Socket);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ThreadList.size(); i++)ThreadList[i].Running = false;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ThreadList.size(); i++)if(ThreadList[i].Thread.joinable())ThreadList[i].Thread.join();
    return true;
}
//------------------------------------ERRORCONSTS---PUBLIC
#pragma region DeclaringErrorConsts
const int
AsyncSockets::FAIL_SUCCESS = 0x0,
AsyncSockets::FAIL_INIT_WS = 0x1,
AsyncSockets::FAIL_BIND_SOCKET = 0x2,
AsyncSockets::FAIL_LISTEN = 0x3,
AsyncSockets::FAIL_ACCEPT = 0x4;
#pragma endregion
```

So, as you may have noticed, I'm trying to do this with std::thread, vectors, and winsock. And the point is to have a function as an argument for StartSockets, that'll do all the sending, receiving, and processing.
Thread objects will be stored in a vector of the RunThread type, that contains an atomic bool that tells whether or not the thread is/should be running, as well as the thread object.

My problem is I'm getting an
`'AsyncSockets::RunThread::RunThread(const AsyncSockets::RunThread &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`
in
`xmemory0 (line 840)`
(c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual
studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.24728\include\xmemory0)

I have no idea why, and since RunThread is a struct and not a function, along with the fact that RunThread::RunThread doesn't make sense, I don't, at all, understand what the profanity is going on. In case it can help any further, I'm on VS 2017 RC on windows 10, win32 console application.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: `std::vector<AsyncSockets::RunThread>` requires a copy-constructible type as the template argument. `RunThread` apparently isn't, probably because of the `std::thread` member (see [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread): *"`std::thread` is not [CopyConstructible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/CopyConstructible)"*).

Comment: Copy-constructibility was required until C++11. Starting with C++11, it depends on the operation you perform on the `std::vector`, that places additional restrictions on the template parameter type. Your `push_back` call requires copy-constructibility, though. If you replace that with [emplace_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) you should be good.